# How do I add an svn trunk as a git branch using git-svn?

Tags: git, svn

I'm working on a project that uses git, and I am new to git myself so apologies if I get terminology/concepts wrong. Another developer joined the team who refuses to use git and maintains his own svn repository. Is there a way to add his svn trunk as a git branch? Thanks!

Comment: +1 for having to put up that other developer

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do that

```
git svn branch -n  -m "Branch for xyz" xyz_def
```